# How to access the values of a data class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, data-class

Here's the codes that is working:

```
data class Abc(
    val a: String,
    val b: String,
    val c: String,
    val d: D
) {
    data class D(
        val e: String,
        val f: String,
        val g: String
    )
}

fun main() {
    val xx = Abc("a1", "b2", "c3", Abc.D("e4", "f5", "g6"))
    xx::class.memberProperties.forEach {
        if (it.returnType.classifier == String::class) {
            println("${it.name} is a String -> ${it.returnType.classifier == String::class} ")
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is this:

```
a is a String -> true 
b is a String -> true 
c is a String -> true
```

Now I would like to access the values of each String members and make the output look like this instead:

```
a is a String -> true -> and the value is a1 
b is a String -> true -> and the value is b2 
c is a String -> true -> and the value is c3
```

How should I change the `println` line? Intuitively I have tried something like:

```
println("${it.name} is a String -> ${it.returnType.classifier == String::class} -> and the value is ${xx.get(it)}")
```

but it didn't work ...

Comment: If you need to loop through the properties, I'd suggest that maybe a class isn't a good fit for your situation; would e.g. a map be better? Reflection might seem attractive if you're used to using it in more dynamic languages; but in Kotlin, it's usually needed only for specific cases such as frameworks, plugins, compiler tools, and interoperability. It's ugly, slow, fragile, insecure, and hard to read, and so it's a strong code smell; there's usually a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KProperty1` has method called `call`, which takes an instance as argument:

```
println("${it.name} is a String -> ${it.returnType.classifier == String::class} -> and the value is ${it.call(xx)}")
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for! Bravo!!!